# What is the relevance of Amon Tauromahian's name change to Longinus

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy, siege-of-terra

At the end of the first wall my favorite Custode Amon Tauromachian is assigned to watch over Euphrate Keeler and those following the Lectitio Divinitatus and worshipping the Emperor

As part of this duty Malcador suggests the addition of a name that name is Longinus.

The way it is done seems to indicate this should be some big moment of revelation, or link to other 40K lore, but I can't find any reference to this character in any other 40K lore.

Is there something I am missing here, does he appear in a host of post-*Heresy* books or source material? Or is this instead suggesting a story yet to be told?

In the story on renaming him Malcador explains the historical relevance to the name indicating that an ancient story suggests he was the bearer of the spear of destiny.

Comment: [Evangelion taught me about Longinus and his spear](https://evangelion.fandom.com/wiki/Spear_of_Longinus). (hint Jesus)

Comment: His name did not change to longinus, it mearely got added to his name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing alot of digging I have stumbled on this, taken from the audio drama Our Martyrd Lady (as an aside Catherine Tate is one of the voice actors). Set post Guiliman's resurection.

> Longinus is the same custodes companion who took the sister of battle
>   founder Alicia Dominica to see the emperor 4,000 years ago and he is
>   still on active service. He mused that it is not a coincident that he
>   has again interfered in the affairs of the Ecclesiarchy. Everyone was
>   shocked! Celestine went on her knees and presented the blade of Saint
>   Katherine to Longinus but he refused. This probably means the
>   custodian are functionally immortal and some of them do not "slow
>   down" at all even after 4,000 years. Some juicy tidbits about the
>   custodian here. Apparently the emperor companions change shift every
>   100 years and in that time their armor can become blackened by the
>   emperor's psychic might. Some companions even have their minds burnt
>   out completely.
>
> IMHO they should add Longinus to the audiobook cover, he has a huge
>   role! Although his name of and rank is a little bit in your
>   face.https://www.reddit.com/r/40kLore/comments/awg51g/our_matyred_lady_audio_drama_spoilers/

So it looks like it was meant to create a moment of ohhhh its him, and my guess is the character will make more of an appearance in the 41st millenium books.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know anything about Horus Heresy or Warhammer 40,000, but since you don't know of any relevance of Loginus in existing Warhammer 40K lore, maybe the name is supposed to be significant outside of Horus Heresy and Warhammer 40K.

There was an ancient Roman *gens* or clan *Cassia*, one branch of it was the *Cassius Longinus* family  with many known members from Quintus Cassius Longinus, mentioned in 252 BC, to Gaius Cassius Longinus, consul in AD 30, alive in the time of Vespasian.

One Gaius cassius Longinus was a leading instigator of the plot to assassinate Caesar in 44 BC.

There were other Roman families with the family name Longinus, belonging to other clans, for example there was a Roman general Gnaeus Pompeius Longinus who died in AD 105.

Lucius Cassis Longinus was Consul in AD 30, and was married to Juliu Drusilla, sister of Caligula and great granddaughter of Augustus, from 33 to 37.  Junia Lepidia, a great great granddaughter of Augustus, married a Gaius Cassius Longinus and was the grandmother of a Domitia Longina who married Emperor Domitian.

In the Gospel of John (19:31-19:37), usually dated to about AD 80 to 100, a Roman soldier is said to have speared the body of Christ on the cross to see if he was dead.  The spear used by that soldier is called "The Holy Lance", "The Spear of Destiny", etc., and several alleged holy lances have been venerated as it in various places.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Lance[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Lance)

A text called the *Acts of Pilate* or *Gospel of Nicodemus* is an apocryphal gospel possibly written in the fourth century (AD 301-400).

> The Gospel of Nicodemus names several minor New Testament figures who were not named in the canonical texts; for example, the soldier who speared Jesus on the cross is named as Longinus and the two criminals crucified beside Jesus are named as Dimas and Gestas.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_Nicodemus[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_Nicodemus)

> The name is probably Latinized from the Greek lonche (λόγχη), the word used for the lance mentioned in John 19:34.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longinus[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longinus)

So not only were there famous historical people named Longinus, a character in the New Testament was later named Longinus, and as you might expect, there were many strange stories written about that Longinus by various Christian writers between late antiquity and the present.

> Longinus did not start out as a saint. An early tradition, found in the 4th-century pseudepigraphal "Letter of Herod to Pilate", claims that Longinus suffered for having pierced Jesus, and that he was condemned to a cave where every night a lion came and mauled him until dawn, after which his body healed back to normal, in a pattern that would repeat till the end of time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longinus[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longinus)

> Longinus is venerated, generally as a martyr, in the Roman Catholic Church, the Eastern Orthodox Church, and the Armenian Apostolic Church. His feast day is kept on 16 October in the Roman Martyrology, which mentions him, without any indication of martyrdom, in the following terms: "At Jerusalem, commemoration of Saint Longinus, who is venerated as the soldier opening the side of the crucified Lord with a lance".[11] The pre-1969 feast day in the Roman Rite is 15 March. The Eastern Orthodox Church commemorates him on 16 October. In the Armenian Apostolic Church, his feast is commemorated on 22 October.[12]
>
> The statue of Saint Longinus, sculpted by Gian Lorenzo Bernini, is one of four in the niches beneath the dome of Saint Peter's Basilica, Vatican City. A spearpoint fragment said to be from the Holy Lance is also conserved in the Basilica.
>
> Longinus and his legend are the subject of the Moriones Festival held during Holy Week on the island of Marinduque, the Philippines.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longinus[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longinus)

More than one modern writer has depicted Longinus as destined to walk the Earth until the second coming of Christ, much like the Wandering Jew of Medieval legends.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longinus[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longinus)

For example, the television program *Roar* (1997) had a Gaius Cassius Longinus among the Roman invaders of Ireland in AD 400.

> One of the major villains in the program was Longinus, played by Sebastian Roché, an immortal cursed by God for interfering with his plans. By Christian tradition, Longinus was the centurion who stabbed Jesus Christ with his spear during the Crucifixion. This spear, the Spear of Destiny, was supposedly the only weapon that could release Longinus from his curse. The show freely mixed Christian mythology, Celtic mythology, Druidism, and smatterings of history.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longinus)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roar_(American_TV_series)[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roar_(American_TV_series))

Therefore, it is possible that the name of Longinus is supposed to evoke memories of Gaius Cassius Longinus who led the plot to assassinate Gaius Julius Caesar, or of the Longinus of Christian tradition, who has been considered both anti Christian and as a Christian convert, saint, and martyr, and is sometimes depicted as immortal.

Comment: Malcador makes this reference when he renames him, briefly explaining why he chose the name stating that in history he wielded a lance,

Comment: @Jasper  I corrected that mispelling.

Answer (score 3):

The significance of the name does not come from anything in *Warhammer 40,000*.  Rather, it is a reference to Christian folklore.  Wikipedia explains:

> "Longinus"... is the name given to the unnamed Roman soldier who pierced the side of Jesus with a lance and who in medieval and some modern Christian traditions is described as a convert to Christianity.  His name first appeared in the apocryphal Gospel of Nicodemus.  The lance is called in Christianity the "Holy Lance" (lancea) and the story is related in the Gospel of John during the Crucifixion.  This act is said to have created the last of the Five Holy Wounds of Christ.
>
> This individual, unnamed in the Gospels, is further identified in some versions of the legend as the centurion present at the Crucifixion, who said that Jesus was the son of God.  Longinus' legend grew over the years to the point that he was said to have converted to Christianity after the Crucifixion, and he is traditionally venerated as a saint in the Roman Catholic Church, Eastern Orthodox Church, and several other Christian communions.

As such, the name is symbolic of a solider convert.

Comment: Malcador references this when he gives him the name

Answer (score 0):

Others have done a great explanation of Longinus as the centurion that pierced the side of christ, and I believe this is the reference Malcador was making.  But from a 40k perspective what does it MEAN?

Given the entirety of Amon's plot in the First Wall is about his disbelief in the Emperor's divinity I think Malcador's choice of name is foreshadowing the fact that Amon will eventually change his mind about the Divinity of the Emperor.  At the very least may become, as Longinus is supposed to have in the apocrypha, a Defender of the Faith.  It would not surprise me if Amon's actions later during the Siege or post-siege prevents a purge of the Lectitio's followers.

Conversely, the name may have been given to Amon not as foreshadowing, but as a direct result of his heroic actions to defend Euphrati Keeler.  Keeler is at this point the ONLY Saint/universal spiritual leader (even if only as figurehead) for the infant Cult of the Emperor.  Her death may well have ended the Cult as a somewhat-coherent faith.  Amon's saving her made him a literal "Defender of the Faith." Malcador may be being a bit ironic with the name, as he knows Amon has little time for, and no belief in, the theory that the Emperor is a god.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding. 
His name did not change into Longinus, it got added to his name.

Whenever a Custodian does something note worthy in his life be it a life merit or a combat glory they get a name for it which is added to their name. Custodians like valdor had a name that consisted of thousands of names.

When Amon completed his Blood games in the short story blood games by Dan Abnett he gained the name "Leng" as that was the part of the imperial palace where he completed the blood games.

And now for performing this deed the name Longinus was added to this.

Currently Amon's full known name would be: Amon Tauromachian Xigaze Lepron 
Cairn Hedrossa [...] Pyrope [...] Leng Longinus. With each of this names having a seperate meaning and origin.

So no he didn't get renames to Longinus, but longinus is now part of his name.
This is a ritual that has been with the custodes since the start of the order.

Comment: My mistake just re listened yes he had it added at the end.